# How can I run hortonworks sandbox environment on google cloud instance?

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, bigdata, cloud

I want to learn hadoop and hence downloaded hortonworks sandbox on my local  machine and opened it on vmbox. But due to lack of sufficient RAM I am thinking about using a cloud vm instance. I used wget to install hortonworks sandbox on instance but it is in ova file ? How can I open it ? How can I start using hadoop eenvironment on my instance ? I want to get into ambari GUI through my cloud instance. Is there any way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot install Hortonworks sandbox from an `ova` into a VM instance. The sandbox is a virtual machine setup for installation on your desktop into products such as VirtualBox. Your Google Compute Engine is a VM so you cannot install a VM into a Google VM.

Setting up Hadoop on a single VM instance is fairly easy, and there are numerous tutorials on the Internet. Google also offers Dataproc as a service which is a very good setup of Hadoop, Sparc, etc. However, setting up Hadoop manually with all of the applications that Hortonworks offers will take effort. This is why products like Dataproc exist, to remove that setup burden.

Comment: So getting Dataproc on my vm instance will get me all the essentials for hadoop ?

Comment: Dataproc is its own managed service which launches its own VM instances. It does not install onto your instance. Dataproc is very similar to Hortonworks in that it is a Hadoop core, with a number of Hadoop based products such as Sparc, Pig, Hive, Tez, etc. What I like about Dataproc is that I can launch an instance or a full cluster in about 90 seconds. Great product.